# What is the logical error in my implementation of Prim's algorithm for minimum spanning tree?

Tags: c++, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

```
#define ll long long
ll prims(int n)
{
     ll ans;
    vector<bool> used (n); 

    #define INF 1000000000000LL


    vector<ll> min_e (n, INF), sel_e (n, -1);

     min_e[0]=-1*INF;

     ll dis=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int v=-1;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
             if (!used[j] && (v == -1 || min_e[j] < min_e[v]))
            v = j;
        }
        used[v] = true;
        if(sel_e[v]!=-1)
        cout << v << " " << sel_e[v] << endl;

    for (int to=0; to<n; ++to)
        if (g[v][to] < min_e[to]) {
            min_e[to] = g[v][to];
            sel_e[to] = v;
        }

    }
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cout<<i<<" "<<sel_e[i]<<" "<<g[i][sel_e[i]]<<endl;


    return dis;
}
```

I am trying to apply Prim's algorithm for a dense undirected graph for negative edge weights but I am unable to understand why it is producing wrong outputs for nearly all cases.
I am using an adjacency matrix g[N][N] for storing the edges.

Actually the output for my current code is a minimum spanning tree with cycles. Why is the cycle checking mechanism not working?

Comment: `pow()` isn't guaranteed to return exact powers for integer inputs. That's one.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze:I have corrected it.Still no improvement in the result,

Comment: Please **never ever use a `#define` instead of a `typedef`**.

Comment: It could be `min_e[0]=-1*INF` if you later add min_e, or the fact that sel_e[0] = -1, so you can't query g[0][sel_e[0]].

Comment: @abeln:min_e[0]=-1*INF why this could produce errors.

Comment: @abeln:Actually the result of  my code is producing a tree with cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem is here:

```
for (int to=0; to<n; ++to)
    if (g[v][to] < min_e[to]) {
        min_e[to] = g[v][to];
        sel_e[to] = v;
    }
}
```

You should only update `sel_e` and `min_e` if `to` hasn't been visited yet.

Otherwise, consider this case:

`0 -- 1 -- 2`

where `w({0, 1}) = 10`, and `w({1, 2} = 1)`. You would set `sel_e[1] = 2`, even though you need `sel_e[1] = 0`.